# Script not logging last element of a list into a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python class (**`TimeTesting`**) which has 3 methods inside it -

1. **`TimeTest1`** - Gets the current time and introduces a sleep of 1 second.
2. **`TimeTest2`** - Gets the current time and calculates the difference between time obtained in **`TimeTest1`** and the time obtained in the function **`TimeTest2`**.
3. **`LogOperation`** - Logs the operation to a csv file with the headers being `IterationNumber`, `T1Value`, `T2Value` and `TimeDifference`.

I am running all the three functions in a loop for 10 times. But the last iteration (i.e. the 10th one) is not being captured in the log file.
Below is my code.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import csv
import collections

MyVar1 = range(1,11)
DataList = []

class TimeTesting:
    def TimeTest1(self):
        self.T1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.LogFileHeader = ['IterationNumber', 'T1Value', 'T2Value', 'TimeDifference']
        print('TimeTest1 function called')

    def TimeTest2(self):
        self.T2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.TimeDiff = self.T2 - self.T1
        print('Timetest2 function called')

    #Log operation function
    def LogOperation(self, Var1):        
        with open('LogFile.csv', 'w') as LogList:
            write = csv.writer(LogList, delimiter = "|", lineterminator = "\n") 
        
            #Extracting the header from the log file
            with open('LogFile.csv', 'r') as ReadLogFile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(ReadLogFile)
                fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
                FileHeaderStringFormat = str(fieldnames)

            #Converting the header from the TimeTest1 function
            TempResult1 = str(self.LogFileHeader)
            LogHeaderStringFormat = TempResult1.replace("', '", "|")

            #Comparing FileHeaderStringFormat and LogHeaderStringFormat
            a = set(FileHeaderStringFormat)
            b = set(LogHeaderStringFormat)  
  
            if collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b):
                write.writerows(DataList)
                DataList.append((Var1, self.T1, self.T2, self.TimeDiff))
            else:
                write.writerow(self.LogFileHeader)
                write.writerows(DataList)
                DataList.append((Var1, self.T1, self.T2, self.TimeDiff))


ob = TimeTesting()

for item in MyVar1:
    ob.TimeTest1()
    ob.TimeTest2()
    ob.LogOperation(item)
```

Below is the log file that is being generated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
 write.writerow(self.LogFileHeader)
 write.writerows(DataList)
 DataList.append((Var1, self.T1, self.T2, self.TimeDiff))
```

if you rewrite them as

```
 DataList.append((Var1, self.T1, self.T2, self.TimeDiff))
 write.writerow(self.LogFileHeader)
 write.writerows(DataList)
```

You were appending the list after you write the row.

Comment: Gosh!
I missed the minute detail. Thanks much.